# ActiveMQ consumer not receiving the desired amount of messages

Tags: multithreading, jms, activemq-classic, quartz-scheduler, message-queue

I have java application in which a Quartz Task runs every `300`ms and try to retrieve a number of messages from ActiveMQ Queue let's say `5` and process them each requested bulk needs about `1` minute to be processed to free the Quartz Scheduler worker

- All threads use the same connection which is locked by a synchronized block on the receive method like this:

```
protected List<?> receive(int bulkSize, String queueName, long receiveTimeoutMillis) {
        LinkedList messages = new LinkedList();

        try {
            QueueReceiver receiver = (QueueReceiver)this.receivers.get(queueName);
            if (receiver != null) {
                ObjectMessage message = null;
                int index = 1; 

                do {
                        message = (ObjectMessage)receiver.receive(receiveTimeoutMillis);

                    if (message != null) {
                        messages.add(message.getObject());
                        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                            LOGGER.debug("Message received from: " + receiver.getQueue().getQueueName() + " jms message id:" + message.getJMSMessageID());
                        }

                        message.acknowledge();
                    }

                    if (message == null) {
                        break;
                    }

                    ++index;
                } while(index <= bulkSize);

             
                LOGGER.info("Consumed " + (index - 1) + " messages from " + queueName + ", elapsed time: " + stopWatch.getTime() + " ms");
            } else {
                LOGGER.warn("Queue not found " + queueName);
            }
        } catch (Exception var10) {
            LOGGER.warn("error in performing receive: " + var10.getMessage(), var10);
        }

        return messages;
    }
```

`receiveTimeoutMillis` is always `150` ms , the `bulkSize` is `5` as I said.

when I start my application each thread uses this method gets a bulk of `5` messages but after a couple of minutes they all start to get `0` to `2` messages although the Queue is **Full** with messages

I don't have any clue why this is happening!,so please give me any hint to check it!

## Notes

- even though I increase the `timeout` of the `receive` method from the Queue still the receiver doesn't get any messages!
- in the log I see the following messages from each thread running the above code:

```
2019-01-29 14:59:23,893 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:24,329 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Consumed 1 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 282 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:24,500 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:24,793 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:25,097 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-18] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:25,403 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-18] Consumed 1 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 153 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:25,693 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:25,996 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:26,300 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:26,595 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:26,898 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:27,193 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
2019-01-29 14:59:27,496 INFO  com.peer39.commons.pattern.jms.JMSService - [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-15] Consumed 0 messages from TRANSLATOR, elapsed time: 150 ms
```

I am adding the daemon thread that runs every `300` ms

```
public class Daemon extends ParallelQuartzDaemon {

   @Override
    protected ICollectorAgent.ProcessStatus executeWork(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext,
                                                        Map<String, Double> properties,
                                                        Map<String, String> alerts) throws Exception {

        ICollectorAgent.ProcessStatus processStatus = ICollectorAgent.ProcessStatus.SUCCESS;
        List<FlowRequest> flowRequests = getFlowRequestsForTranslation();
        if (!flowRequests.isEmpty()) {
           //DO Work! //takes 1-2 minutes!
        }
        return processStatus;
    }

 private List<FlowRequest> getFlowRequestsForTranslation() {
     translatorContext.getTranslatorJMSService().getFlowRequestsToTranslate(5);
    }

}
```

and the JMS class:

```
public class TranslatorJMSService extends JMSService {

   public List<FlowRequest> getFlowRequestsToTranslate(int count) {
        final Long jmsReceiveTimeoutMillis = translatorConfiguration.getJmsReceiveTimeoutMillis();
            return (List<FlowRequest>) receive(count, queueName, jmsReceiveTimeoutMillis);
    }

}
```

and last, the receive method is mentioned above.

thanks!

Comment: What prefetch size is being used?

Comment: You say, "All threads use the same connection which is locked by a synchronized block on the receive method like this..." However, I don't see any synchronization in the code you pasted, and I wouldn't expect any synchronization on the `javax.jms.Connection` would be necessary as it should already be thread-safe. Can you elaborate on how & why your doing this?

Comment: The code seems to indicate that you're caching the `javax.jms.QueueReceiver` instances. Is that correct? Is there just one `QueueReceiver` per queue?

Comment: The prefetch size is 1 as each message takes a lot of time to process and caching them on the consumer leads to out of memory issue because of the slow processing speed, regarding your question about synchroning the method I added a synchronized block in the task calling the above method so only one thread at a time can access the queue receiver , I am really caching the receivers but there is only one per Queue.

Comment: I added the synchronization because I thouth the issue was caused by multiple threads accessing the same session of the recevier mentioned above but the issue still exist also after adding the lock on the method above so I am assuming it is not the case here!

Comment: At this point I wouldn't cache anything. You can use a single connection, but each time try creating & closing a new session and a new consumer. That will eliminate the need for synchronization and avoid any concurrency issues as well.

Comment: I don't have a total control on creating and editing the sessions or the consumer as they do exist in an external Jar file which I am using as a dependency, why do you think that there is an issue in caching the consumer, at first I thought it was Null in some cases but it is not! , furthermore isn't closing and starting a new session and a Q consumer is unnecessary overhead that will do performance degradation ?

Comment: I changed the time for each thread to run after 30 seconds instead of 300ms but that also didn't work!

Comment: I'm just trying to simplify the code to eliminate *potential* problems. I've found this to be a helpful practice when debugging. Eliminating potential problems systematically is just basic problem solving. I've also found that premature optimization can needlessly complicate code and introduce errors. There's no clear evidence that creating a new session & consumer is going to have a statistically significant negative impact on your application's performance.

Comment: Ok, I will try to change the method by overriding it in a subclass to test what you are saying , will let you know, thanks!

Comment: No, that didn't work the same issue I keep getting.

Comment: when I debug the server and run over the receive method it gets the number of messages specified but when exiting debug mode it takes 1-2 messages instead of 5!

Comment: @Justin ustin-bertram I think the issue lies in the receive(timeout) method although there are messages pending in the Q , this method took about 8 seconds to retrieve the data, why this is happening although the data constantly available in the Q?

Comment: It's really impossible to say at this point. I suggest you start working on a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can share. This will help you in two ways - (1) you may discover the problem on your own as you eliminate potential problems through the minimization process, and (2) it will help others reproduce the problem your seeing and make it more likely that you'll get help.

Comment: @JustinBertram I have updated my question and added some code please tell me if that is not sufficient! , thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, some code pasted into the question is not sufficient for an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In general, I'd recommend creating a Mavenized project and putting it somewhere like GitHub where users can pull the code, follow a few clear steps to set up the environment (the fewer the better), and then run the code to reproduce the issue. The ability to reproduce and verify the results of an experiment is the essential basis of all science.